# How to setup exception handlers for an existing JUnit4 project?

Tags: exception, junit, global, unhandled

I have a JUnit project with 100s of lines of code and 100s of test cases already automated. But this project does not have any exceptions managed code. Hence while running the test cases from Eclipse, if there was an exception like NullPointer, etc, the execution halts in Eclipse with the error message of the Exception. I would like to handle these unhandled Exceptions in my project so that these messages are logged. Is there an option to handle these exceptions globally which I can setup for this project. Since it has 100s of methods it would be difficult to add exceptions for each and every method that already exists.

My project runs in Java 7 + JUnit 4

Any pointers will of great help. Thanks in advance!

Update 1:

I found a solution by creating a class that implements TestRule. But in order to get this working, I will have to add @Rule statements in all of my existing test scripts which are 100s of files. 
Is there a work around for this so that i can avoid editing all those 100s test scripts.

Regards,
Janaki

Comment: can you re-describe the problem in other/more words? i read your question 3 times and can not understand it!

Comment: Please clearify: do you have failing tests, because your code throws an exception?